# Java DefaultListModel not added to JList

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am attempting to follow the MVC pattern so have 3 classes. The elements are being added to the model successfully and then passed onto the view. Nothing is using shown in the JList which appears on the screen, it just remains blank. Heres the code and thanks to anyone that can help! When I set my albumLabel text to the size of model it gets set to 1050, so I can assume that the data is getting back to my view class, just not into the display. Everything is declared and I have left out some bits which are not related to this.

My Controller class

```
class BrowseListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
        chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);        
        theModel.getMusicList(chooser);

        theView.setListModel(theModel.getListModel());
        theView.updateUI();
    }
}
```

My Model Class

```
public ArrayList<File> getMusicList(JFileChooser chooser){
    if(chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){ 
        File folder = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());
        displayDirectoryContents(folder);
        if(allMusic.size() <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No music files found");
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No Selection ");
    }
    return allMusic;
} 

public void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            displayDirectoryContents(file);
        }
        else if(file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
            allMusic.add(file);
            model.addElement(file.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("file:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }           
    }
}

public DefaultListModel getListModel(){
    return model;
}
```

My View Class

```
MP3View(){        

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600, 200);

    model = new DefaultListModel();
    musicJList = new JList(model);

    metaDataPanel.add(new JScrollPane(musicJList), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.add(metaDataPanel);        
}

public void setListModel(DefaultListModel model){
    this.model = model;
    albumLabel.setText(Integer.toString(model.getSize()));
}

void addBrowseMusicListener(ActionListener listenForBrowse){
    browseButton.addActionListener(listenForBrowse);
}
```

Comment: do you update your gui once you manipulate your model?

Comment: @MartinFrank yea I call it in my controller class `theView.updateUI();` that executes this `metaDataPanel.validate();`

Comment: Where are you setting the `model` to the `JList`? I am not seeing `JList.setModel()` call anywhere.

Comment: @Codebender yea thats being called in the view class here `musicJList = new JList(model);`

Comment: i see only that you call `theView.setListModel(theModel.getListModel());`in your actionlistener - when looking at `setListModel(..)` you never call any update UI methods...

Comment: @DominicE, but that's in the constructor. It won't be called after you call `theView.setListModel()`. So the model of the `JList` is not updated.

Comment: @MartinFrank I have just tried to move the `updateUI();` into my `setListModel()` function, still getting the same result. I thought that when changes are made to a model they automatically update?

Comment: i thought the same...

Comment: @Codebender yes that has worked! Used the setModel() method as you said and it worked, thanks! Was not aware that you had to do this if modifying the modal in another class, sorry still a noob at this!. If you can move your comment to the answer and i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the model to the `JList`.

When you do,

```
model = new DefaultListModel();
musicJList = new JList(model);
```

The `JList`'s model is set to the `new DefaultListModel()` object.

But after that, you are doing,

```
theView.setListModel(theModel.getListModel()); // You should put this new model to the JList.
```

So, in you `setListModel()` method, do

```
public void setListModel(DefaultListModel model){
    this.model = model;
    this.musicJList.setModel(this.model); // Add this line.
    albumLabel.setText(Integer.toString(model.getSize()));
}
```